# I get the following mistake when I compile it

Tags: java

```
public class Hw7pr1
{
 public static void main(String[] args);

    String eName;
    double payrate;

    public Hw7pr1(String name, double rate)
    {

         eName = name;
         payrate = rate;

    }
    public String getEName()

    {
         return eName;
    }
    public void setEName(String name)

    {
         eName = name;
    }

    public double getPayrate()

    {
         return payrate;
    }

    public void setPayrate(double payrate)

    {
         this.payrate = payrate;
    }
}
```

This is the mistake I get when compiling it.

```
Hw7pr1.java:3: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
public void main(String[] args);
                ^
```

Comment: the body of the main function is missing.

Comment: Your brackets are missing.

Comment: Your code looks messed up. But you should remove the ; in front of main and put in { } as in like functions.

Comment: Did you even Google this? A cursory search for `missing method body, or declare abstract` turns up numerous other questions on StackOverflow solving the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the semicolon after your main method declaration

should be like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove ";" at the end of your main method and add instead a bracket

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

and at the end of your main method (which seems not really used - empty) a closing one

```
}
```

The class:

```
public class Hw7pr1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // do something
  }

  String eName;
  double payrate;

  public Hw7pr1(String name, double rate) {

    eName = name;
    payrate = rate;

  }

  public String getEName()

  {
    return eName;
  }

  public void setEName(String name)

  {
    eName = name;
  }

  public double getPayrate()

  {
    return payrate;
  }

  public void setPayrate(double payrate)

  {
    this.payrate = payrate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. That still wouldn't compile.

Comment: I see your edit. That still wouldn't compile.